# Application error while copying data from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

While copying data from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` I am getting

> "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

I am using following vba code:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:E14").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(10, 2)
```

I can't find anything wrong in this. Why vba is throwing error in this?

Comment: Possible reason: copy range has different size than paste range

Comment: are there any other lines of code?

Comment: Yes. this is just a snippet from my code

Comment: Another possible reason - this is not the line that generates error. I wasn't able to replicate it.

Comment: I got the issue.. 1 cell was merged, that is why it could not copy. Now its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because some cells in the range where I tried pasting the data were merged.